# How to display the most recent clipboard content when I right click on chrome using a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I right click on Chrome, I want one of the menu items to contain my most recent clipboard content. So, I can quickly glance at what is copied, without pasting it anywhere. Basically I want the extension to do this(good even if it doesn't go to a submenu):[I already downloaded this, this feature doesn't work like intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg41x.png)
I'm very new to creating extensions, I haven't made a lot of progress, please help. And if other alternatives exist let me know.

current manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Clipboard Keeper",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Stores the most recent clipboard content",
  "permissions": [
    "clipboardRead",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

current background file:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.type === "getClipboardContent") {
    const clipboardContent = navigator.clipboard.readText();
    sendResponse({ content: clipboardContent });
  }
});
```

Current content.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id: "clipboardMenu",
  title: "Most Recent Clipboard Content",
  contexts: ["selection"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  if (info && info.menuItemId === "clipboardMenu") {
    // Read the most recent clipboard content
    const clipboardContent = navigator.clipboard.readText();

    // Display the content in the context menu
    const menuItem = chrome.contextMenus.create({
      id: "clipboardContent",
      title: clipboardContent,
      parentId: "clipboardMenu"
    });
  }
});
```

Please note these are all very badly put together and doesn't work at all like I would like